# How to solve AWS Elastic Beanstalk 504 Timeout Error?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk for hosting Express/Node.js API server.
It's working well with just normal APIs but I am getting this 504 Timeout error with only one API which may take time for more than 20 mins at max.
So, I thought I needed to increase max request time of Nginx and Node.js server and I did it by configuring AWS EB .extensions and .platform variables.

Here is what I did.

**.platform/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf**

```
client_header_timeout 3000s;
client_body_timeout 3000s;
send_timeout 3000s;
proxy_connect_timeout 3000s;
proxy_read_timeout 3000s;
proxy_send_timeout 3000s;
```

**.ebextensions/network.config**

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 3000
```

But I am still getting this error and I can't understand why this is happening.

- Plus Note: Elastic Beanstalk server is covered by CloudFront and AWS Route 53 for giving it public domain address and HTTPS connection.

If somebody knows how to fix this, it will be appreciated a lot.

Comment: Are you using a load balancer? Also check the Connection idle timeout parameter

Comment: Thanks for your question, OARP. But I don't know if I am using load balancer or not. I just created elastic beanstalk by aws console eb create wizard. Please let me know where I can find those connection idle timeout parameter settings.

Comment: In your environment go to "Configuration" section and check the "Load balancer" category. Here you will find if you are using a ELB

Comment: I checked my eb configuration. In the load balancer category, I can see Listeners: 1, Load balancer type: application, Processes: 1, Rules: 0, Shared: false, Store logs: disabled.
Is this ELB or not?

Comment: Yes, try checking the idle timeout setting https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout

Comment: OARP! It was really thankful to configure idle timeout settings. Now it's working well with origin url or EB instance. But the problem is that 504 timeout error is still happening when I try to request through CloudFront and Route 53. As I mentioned in my post, I am using CloudFront and Route 53 to use HTTPS connection. It seems a little steps are remaining. Would you like to teach me how to solve last problem?

Comment: Thanks, OARP! I solved my problem. Can you create answer here so that I can accept and choose it with solved?

Comment: Sure. And just for curiosity, what was the previous value in the ELB timeout?

Comment: It was 30 seconds. I was just wondering why connection was closed before 60 seconds since I thought all the default limit time was 60 seconds on AWS services. Now I understand what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks @OARP it works for me as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case you are using a "Load balanced" environment type, check the "Connection idle timeout" setting of the Load Balancer.

To validate if your env uses a ELB go to "*Elastic Beanstalk*" -> "<*your_environment*> -> "*Configuration*" section and check if the "Load balancer" category is present. Here you can find also the type of ELB you are using. Then change the Connection idle timeout setting in the [EC2 console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#connection-idle-timeout) to a proper value.